# What part of the Manifest do I change to send data from a service to a activity on resume?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-intent, android-service, intentfilter

I have a service that continues to do what the activity was doing when the user navigates away from the application, and when they return, the service send the data back to the activity to then display, but I don't know what part of the Manifest to change. Sample code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What part of the AndroidManifest.xml?  None.  I would think you'd want to bind to the service from your activity.  then you can ask it directly.  Also, have the server send out a broadcast when whatever its doing is ready, in case the Activity is already open.

Comment: How would you bind a service? Is what you're talking about IBinder? Is it like the LocalBinder in the Local Service code in the docs? If so how would you send integers or strings with that? If not either of those two, how would you do it? Sample code please.

Comment: Or a link to a better tutorial that addresses my problem.

Comment: Actually I figured out what you meant, did more research and fixed my problem. Thank you.